# Can concurrntHashMap guarantee true thread safety and concurrency at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

We know that ConcurrentHashMap can provide concurrent access to multiple threads to boost performance , and inside this class, segments are synchronized up (am I right?). Question is, can this design guarantee the thread safety? Say we have 30+ threads accessing &changing an object mapped by the same key in a ConcurrentHashMap instance, my guess is, they still have to line up for that, don't they?

From my recollection that the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" says the ConcurrentHashMap provide concurrent reading and a decent level of concurrent writing. in the aforementioned scenario, and if my guess is correct, the performance won't be better than using the Collection's static synchonization wrapper api?

Thanks for clarifying,
John

Comment: [I'm putting my answer in comment, as I'm not 100% sure of what I claim.]  There are 2 reasons why ConcurrentHashMap can be faster than the wrapper: A) ConcurrentHashMap can _read_ without locking, B) it is constructed with concurrent atomic variables, which use the newer cpu cache synchronizing operations ("conditional update"), which can be much faster than older synchronization methods.

Answer (score 6):

You will still have to synchronize any access to the object being modified, and as you suspect all access to the same key will still have contention.  The performance improvement comes in access to different keys, which is of course the more typical case.

Comment: +1 for actually reading the question (unlike my answer, sigh).

Comment: "...still have to synchronize..." that's false in most usages of ConcurrentHashMap. See Jed's answer.

Comment: @irreputable: I think this answer is referring to concurrent mutations of a single map value object (not the map itself), which of course the `ConcurrentHashMap` isn't going to help with at all. The question isn't very clear, but that's what it sounds like it asks in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Colin the question is whether most usages of the concurrent map would store mutable objects in it. my experience is no. people who use concurrent map either consciously or instinctively store immutables in it, and changes are published by updating the map, not the values.

Comment: The question states that 30+ threads would be accessing and changing the object, so they must be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

All a `ConcurrentMap` can give you wrt to concurrency is that modifications to the map itself are done atomically, and that any writes *happen-before* any reads (this is important as it provides safe publishing of any reference from the map.

Safe-publishing means that any (mutable) object retrieved from the map will be seen with all writes to it *before* it was placed in the map. It won't help for publishing modifications that are made after retrieving it though.

However, concurrency and thread-safety is generally hard to reason about and make correct if you have mutable objects that are being modified by multiple parties. Usually you have to lock in order to get it right. A better approach is often to use immutable objects in conjunction with the `ConcurrentMap` conditional putIfAbsent/replace methods and linearize your algorithm that way. This *lock-free* style tends to be easier to reason about.

Comment: another option, read the value, if it needs modification clone()/copy it and then when done use CHM.replace(key, oldvalue, newValue).Of course it needs CAS alike loop. The hard part is failing the replace b/c the algorithm must be prepared for. ...Which requires an internal state, etc. I guess locking+putIfAbsent seems easier for most of the people.

Answer (score 2):

> Question is, can this design guarantee the thread safety?

It guarantees the thread safety of the map; i.e. that access and updates on the map have a well defined and orderly behaviour in the presence of multiple threads performing updates simultaneously.

It does guarantee thread safety of the key or value objects.  And it does not provide any form of higher level synchronization.

> Say we have 30+ threads accessing &changing an object mapped by the same key in a ConcurrentHashMap instance, my guess is, they still have to line up for that, don't they?

If you have multiple threads trying to use the same key, then their operations will inevitably be serialized to some degree.  That is unavoidable.

In fact, from briefly looking at the source code, it looks like `ConcurrentHashMap` falls back to using conventional locks if there is too much contention for a particular segment of the map.  And if you have multiple threads trying to access AND update the same key simultaneously, that will trigger locking.

Comment: I'm reading JDK 6 and there is.  It is not in the outer `get` though.  It is the `get` on the segment hashtables.

Comment: the change is only 2 month old: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2011-April/003154.html

Comment: @irreputable Java 6 does in fact do some locking in the event a JVM re-ordering constrcuts an object but initializes the volatile value later.  This cannot actually happen in Java 6 but was never removed (it was possible in Java 5).  That being said, the Java 7 implementation is actually a pretty decent change to the overall class.  But since Java 7 will not have the null volatile value issue again (resolves in 6) its always volatile loads and no locks

Comment: @John The new java memory model took effect since Java 5, not 6. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: @irreputable  You are correct about Java 5 being the introduction about the memory model.  What I was referring to, is that when Java 6 released, the issue that forces the lock on read in Java 5 no longer happened.

Comment: @Stephen, falling back to the locks never happens, there is even a quote of Doug Lea on that and he basically told that this impl. (insisted by Bill Pugh) made many developers confused. Basically the compiler needs to reorder the new Entry assignment w/ the `volatile value` to make it even theoretically possible. It's a bit weird that volatile fields in the c-tor don't enjoy the same spec. like final ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002428/concurrenthashmap-reorder-instruction/5144515#5144515

Answer (score 1):

first remember that a thread safe tool doesn't guarantee thread safe usage of it in and of itself

the `if(!map.contains(k))map.put(k,v);` construct to putIfAbsent for example is not thread safe

and each value access/modification still has to be made thread safe independently

Answer (score 0):

Reads are concurrent, even for the same key, so performance will be better for typical applications.