# Java 8 ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

I've observed that ConcurrentHashMap has been entirely rewritten in Java 8 to be more "lock-free". I've browsed the code of the `get()` method and see that there is no explicit lock mechanism:

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
    int h = spread(key.hashCode());
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
        if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
            if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))
                return e.val;
        }
        else if (eh < 0)
            return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
        while ((e = e.next) != null) {
            if (e.hash == h &&
                ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
                return e.val;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Question:

**How it is possible to see from one thread, modifications done to this hashmap from other threads, since the code isn't under a synchronize umbrella (which would enforce a *happens-before* relation)?**

Note: The entire ConcurrentHashMap is a wrapper of a table:
  `transient volatile Node<K,V>[] table;`

*So `table` is a volatile reference to an array, not a reference to an array of volatile elements!* Which means that if someone is updating an element inside this array, the modification won't be seen in other threads.

Comment: You might find this an (additional) good read: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue235.html

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` actually does perform volatile reads from the array elements, using `Unsafe`. That's what the method [`tabAt`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.tabAt%28java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.Node%5B%5D%2Cint%29) does.

Comment: Just to clarify, @Radiodef the synchronization of `Unsafe` is on `put`s not reads.

Answer (score 14):

### Short answer

The `Node#val` is `volatile` which establishes your happens before ordering.

### Longer answer

`synchronized` isn't a requirement for thread safety, it's one tool in a toolbox to make a system thread safe. You'll have to consider an entire set of actions on this `ConcurrentHashMap` to reason about thread safety.

It's useful to know the original `ConcurrentHashMap` too is non-blocking. Notice pre-Java 8 CHM get

```
V get(Object key, int hash) {
    if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
        HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
        while (e != null) {
            if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
                V v = e.value;
                if (v != null)
                    return v;
                return readValueUnderLock(e); // ignore this
            }
            e = e.next;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this case, there is no blocking, so how does it work? The `HashEntry#value` is `volatile`. That is the synchronization point for thread safety.

The `Node` class for CHM-8 is the same.

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    volatile V val;
    volatile Node<K,V> next;
```

So a non-null val in this case should ensure thee happens-before relationship with respect to actions prior to a put.

Comment: For more information on `ignore this` you can read my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002428/concurrenthashmap-reorder-instruction

Answer (score 5):

The documentation does not state that synchronization occurs. For example it states

> [...] aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent
>   retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

In other words, there is a difference between allowing concurrent usage, and providing synchronized access.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - There is a happens-before edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).
> - If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

and [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)

> Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on actions, defined as follows:
>
> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.
> - The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread.
>
>   Although it may seem a little strange to write a default value to a variable before the object containing the variable is allocated, conceptually every object is created at the start of the program with its default initialized values.
> - The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.
>
>   T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().
> - If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1 synchronizes-with any point where any other thread (including T2) determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an InterruptedException thrown or by invoking Thread.interrupted or Thread.isInterrupted).

That is, reading a volatile field establishes happens-before just like an explicit lock.